# How to solve the differential equation $(1 + t^2) \dot{y} = 2yt + t^2 + t^4$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation that I try to solve:

\begin{equation}
(1 + t^2) \dot{y} = 2yt + t^2 + t^4
\end{equation}

what I do is to first put all $t$'s on one side:

\begin{equation}
\dot{y} =   \frac{2yt + t^2 + t^4}{1+t^2}
\end{equation}

and then to integrate both sides

\begin{equation}
\int \dot{y} dy = \int \frac{2yt + t^2 + t^4}{1+t^2} dt
\end{equation}

and well now I am stuck because I don't really know how to evaluate these complex integrals. I think I should use the method by parts but whenever I try I think I am making mistake somewhere and I am not sure if my steps up till now are correct as well.

Comment: I think you should be able to get solution in terms of power series expansion relatively easily, but maybe that is not what you want.

Comment: @mathreadler and how would I do that? Well I am not sure how to solve it to be honest. I dont need to use any particular method I think

Comment: You can't integrate the right side with that $y$ in there.  This is a linear equation.  Express it in the form $y'+p(t)y = g(t)$.

Comment: You can search for some vector space where derivative and multiplicaiton with polynomial are linear operations. Then your equation becomes a linear equation system in this new space.

Comment: @B.Goddard So if I understand you correctly I should express it as:

$y'- 2yt =\frac{t^2+t^4}{1-t^2}$?

Also how would this help? now the t is on the other side

Comment: Now you can pretend that left hand side is result of Leibniz product theorem for derivatives. Maybe... Not sure.

Comment: The equation is not so "hard". It was arranged to be solvable by you.

Comment: Yes this is why separability is not good to get stuck on using. It is not particular general method of solving equations, but it is easy to backwards-"construct" functions for which it holds (for lazy teachers). The students get the feeling to have learned a powerful method but in fact it is more of an ugly trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite the equation:

$$y'-\frac{2t}{1+t^2}y = \frac{t^4+t^2}{t^2+1} = t^2.$$

The standard technique for linear, first-order DE's is to multiply by the integrating factor

$$\mu = \exp\left(\int p(t) \; dt\right)  = \exp\left(\int \frac{-2t}{1+t^2} \; dt\right)$$

$$=\exp(-\ln(t^2+1)) = \frac{1}{t^2+1}.$$

So now the DE is

$$\frac{1}{t^2+1}y' + \frac{-2t}{(1+t^2)^2}y = \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}. $$

The left side is the derivative of $\frac{1}{t^2+1}y$, so you have

$$\frac{y}{t^2+1} = \int \frac{t^2}{t^2+1} \; dt.$$

Comment: You mishandled a coefficient, making the solution go in a wrong direction.

Answer (score 5):

The *homogeneous* equation is separable,

$$\frac{\dot y}{y}=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}$$ and integrates as

$$\log y=\log(t^2+1)+C$$ or

$$y=C(t^2+1).$$

Now by variation of the constant, after simplification,

$$(t^2+1)^2C'(t)=t^2+t^4$$ then

$$C'(t)=\frac{t^2}{t^2+1}$$ and

$$C(t)=t-\arctan t+D.$$

Finally,

$$y(t)=(t-\arctan t+D)(t^2+1).$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. How did you know that this equation is separable I thought that equation is separable only if I can get in a form $y(x) dy/dx = M(x)$ so only when all x in my case t can be separated and I can multiply the time derivative with the function

Comment: @1muflon1: the equation is *not* seaprable. Read my answer carefully.

Answer (score 3):

$$(1 + t^2) \dot{y} = 2yt + t^2 + t^4
$$
$$(1 + t^2) y'-2yt= t^2 + t^4
$$
It's of the form $(\frac fg)'=\frac {f'g-fg'}{g^2}$
$$\left(\frac {y}{t^2+1}\right)'= \frac {t^2}{1 + t^2}
$$
Integrate
$$\frac {y}{t^2+1}= t-\arctan (t)+K
$$
$$ {y(t)}= {(t^2+1)}(t-\arctan (t)+K
)$$

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate the method I proposed.

We first choose a vector space where we can express differentiation and multiplication by polynomials as linear operators. One such space is the space of polynomials. If we vectorize coefficients of polynomials in increasing order the operators differentiation $({\bf D})$ and multiplication by $t$ $({\bf X})$ will be represented by:

$${\bf D}=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc} &1& & & & \\ & &2& & & \\ & & &3& & \\ & & & &4& \\ & & & & &5\\ & & & & & \end{array}\right],{\bf X}=\left[\begin{array}{cccccc} & & & & & \\1& & & & & \\ &1& & & & \\ & &1& & & \\ & & &1& & \\ & & & &1& \end{array}\right]$$

Now we can express our problem as a matrix equation system:

$${\bf Mx=b}$$

where $\bf b$ is vector for function $t^2+t^4$ and

$${\bf M}=({\bf I}+{\bf X}^2){\bf D}-2{\bf X}$$

Furthermore since this is a linear equation system which is within linear least square problems, we can add a [*regularization term*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization#Generalized_Tikhonov_regularization) to test out how our solution performs for different parameter values (the $D$ constant in Yves' solution and $K$ in Isham's).

solving this equation system for a vectorspace up to $x^{15}$ and for constant term $c_0\in [-1,1]$:

[image]