# Variable change for numerical power series convergence in DE:s?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2976588/213607) it is explained how to numerically solve differential equations using (truncated) power series expansions. This can be useful within some interval of real line. Let us assume some localized truncated power series expansion:

$$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k(x-x_0)^k$$

But as we know monomials grow so quickly that if $\|x-x_0\|\geq 1+\epsilon$, the function value increases very fast. In fact I think we can prove it will be $O(\epsilon^n)$.

Due to the power of compound interest (for you economics nerds) this grows so incredibly fast, so in practice we can only be sure about reasonably nice behaviour within $$\|x-x_0\|\leq 1-\epsilon$$ which will clearly be bounded by $1$ for each individual monomial term.

What techniques can we then use to make a workable approximation of some function anywhere outside of $\|x\|<1$?

Comment: While often occurring in tutorial examples and normalized equations, in general the radius of convergence of the power series is not $1$. What you describe is a characterization of the radius of convergence. (Btw., Bernoulli inequality gives $( 1+ϵ)^n\ge nϵ\to\infty$. Contrarily, $ϵ^n\to 0$ is not as catastrophic as you imagined.) Analytic continuation requires evaluation of infinite series for every coefficient. Padé approximants might be more correct over larger intervals than the original Taylor polynomial, but that is not automatic.

Comment: Of course I know radius of convergence is not 1 in general for Taylor series of functions, but nasty numerical things happen for floating point precision above 1 which is what can impact my algorithm.

Comment: Can you give an example? The only real dangerous thing is that the powers will eventually reach floating point overflow, esp. if you have an algorithm that doubles the degree in every step. Catastrophic cancellation, esp. in roots and for sign-alternating coefficients, also gets more pronounced for larger arguments, but there is no natural $1$ boundary.

Comment: @LutzL I will probably need to think about it for a bit. Anyway thanks for your feedback.

Comment: It is dangerous to evaluate the series close to the radius of convergence. Assume for simplicity that that radius is still $1$, $|x|=1-δ$ and that the coefficient sequence is eventually falling. The criterion for the truncation degree to get some accuracy $ ϵ$ is then that for the series remainder $$|c_{N+1}|\,\frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-|x|}=|c_{N+1}|\frac{(1-δ)^{N+1}}{δ}<ϵ,$$ giving approximately $N>\frac{|\log(δϵ)|}{δ}$. This large degree might then indeed lead to a large accumulation of floating point noise during evaluation.

Comment: Yes, in current form I won't need worry about it, but certain linear fusion techniques would be possible to use which could suffer from this thing you mention. Well it does happen for the linked problem that radius of convergence is 1, poles at $\pm i$ for (derivative of) arctan, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but there special circumstances occur, as the series is alternating so that the remainder is smaller than the next term. With degree $15$  the error at $\pm 1$ is smaller than $\frac1{17}\approx 0.06$ which is good enough for the plot.